# Inkscape menu bar font unreadably light

Tags: inkscape

How do I change the font color for menus in Ubuntu? It's unreadably light.
It looks like the items are unclickable, but the items are clickable. I already tried reinstalling inkscape. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu, I haven't done anything to any settings other than installing a few programs like atom and steam.

[image]